# Python Django css not loading with huge error in console

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I'm making a Django site and the code seems fine, but I get this very long error whenever I load the site from my browser:

```
[23/May/2018 21:01:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1840
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/home/runner/.site- 
packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
return super().__call__(environ, start_response)
File "/home/runner/.site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 
146, in __call__
response = self.get_response(request)
File "/home/runner/.site- 
packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 62, in get_response
return super().get_response(request)
File "/home/runner/.site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 81, 
in get_response
response = self._middleware_chain(request)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[23/May/2018 21:01:20] "GET /static/style.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

I have absolutely no idea what this is supposed to mean, but it loads just find when I use  in my HTML. Whenever I use my static folder and a separate CSS file, this pops up.

This is my base HTML file (Sorry for the bad indent when copy pasting):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>&lt; &lt; LambCentral &gt; &gt;</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "/style.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="maintitle">
<center><h1>LambCentral</h1></center>
</div>
<br>
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
<div class="bottom">
    <center>
        <h2>
            LambCentral
        </h2>
        <h4>
            Satisfy Curiosity
        </h4>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I get that huge error, you can see below it that Django tries to load the CSS but gets a server error (Error 500 aka Pink Error Text)

What am I doing wrong? I'm not new to HTML, but I'm novice in Django, so sorry if it's a newbie mistake.

EDIT: Settings.py: (sorry for bad indent again, copy paste)

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

<Secret key redacted>

# SECURITY WARNING: make sure you update this to your websites URL
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW ALL'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'main.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'main.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
{
    'NAME':

'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator'
},
{
    'NAME':
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator'
},
{
    'NAME':
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator'
},
{
    'NAME':
    'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator'
}
]

#SubPaths
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/tutorials'


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'EST'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "..", "static"),
]
```

EDIT 2: Image

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4fB7.png)

Comment: can you add your `settings.py`

Comment: @Lemayzeur Done